# About Knot Group

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was studying a note and here one concept is not clear to me .
Suppose $K$ be a knot in $R^3$ .Then $K$ is compact subset of $R^3$. So $S^3 \setminus K $ is the union of $R^3 \setminus K $ and a open ball $B$ formed by the one point compactification point together with complement of a large closed ball in $R^3$ which containing $K$. In this note , author claimed that $B \cap (R^3 \setminus K ) $ is homeomorphic to $S^2$ X $R$ . I am not getting this claim( homeomorphism)  ? Can you please explain ?

Comment: Note that $B \cap( \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus K)$ is homeomorphic to $B \setminus \{\infty\}$ , where  $\infty$ is the point of compactification.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, suppose the closed ball containing $K$ is $A = \{x: |x| \le 10\}$. Also say the compactification is $\Bbb{R}^3 \hookrightarrow \Bbb{R}^3 \cup \{*\}$, so $B = \{*\} \cup \{x: |x| > 10\}$. Now $B \cap (\Bbb{R}^3 - K) = \{x: |x| > 10\}$, which you can also regard as $S^2 \times (10, \infty)$.